# move center in AutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, ipad, uilabel, autorotate

Currently I place the UILable in center in portrait mode.

```
UILabel* lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280, 10, 150, 45)];
lbl.text=@"3 out of 5 views";
lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18];
lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

[cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
```

When position change to landscape mode, it's not in center of landscape position. So, I tried with autoresizingMask and it's not working well.

```
lbl.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

How to move the UILable to center always in Landscape and portrait mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it

```
[lbl setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
```